# stanfordnlp differences 3.9.2 -> 4.0.0 changelg

Tags: stanford-nlp

*Changed to UDv2 tokenization (“new” LDC Treebank,for English); handles multi-word-tokens; improved UDv2-based taggers and parsers for English, French, German, Spanish; new French NER;new Chinese segmenter; library updates, bug fixes*
https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html

*Big changes in CoreNLP 4: no LDC-style escaping of tokens (no more -LRB-), change English tokenization to that of “new” LDC treebanks and UD (mainly split hyphens), use UDv2 dependencies and POS for English, French, German, and Spanish (have obj and obl)*
https://twitter.com/stanfordnlp/status/1252657192764796928

Can someone provide a detailed/informative/useable summary of the changes at the interface and at the functional level? If it helps narrow the scope:

English models

Annotation requires()

```
    CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class
    CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class
    CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class
    CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class
    CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation.class
    CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class
    CoreAnnotations.NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation.class
    CoreAnnotations.CanonicalEntityMentionIndexAnnotation.class
    CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class
    SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class
    CoreAnnotations.QuotationsAnnotation.class
```

Pipeline properties

```
    props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "statistical");
    props.setProperty("coref.maxMentionDistance", "15");
    props.setProperty("coref.maxMentionDistanceWithStringMatch", "50");
    props.setProperty("coref.statisical.pairwiseScoreThresholds", ".15");
    props.setProperty("pos.maxlen", "70");
    props.setProperty("ner.maxlen", "70");
    props.setProperty("ner.applyFineGrained", "false");
    props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "true");
    props.setProperty("ner.applyNumericClassifiers", "true");
    props.setProperty("ner.combinationMode", "NORMAL");
    props.setProperty("ner.additional.regexner.mapping", "regexner.txt");
    props.setProperty("quote.maxLength", "70");
    props.setProperty("quote.singleQuotes", "true");
    props.setProperty("quote.asciiQuotes", "true");
    props.setProperty("quote.attributeQuotes", "true");
    props.setProperty("enforceRequirements", "true");
    props.setProperty("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
    props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "70");
```

Comment: Or to focus it down even more.  Assuming a semantic versioning system x.y.z where: z connotes bugfix/performance improvement, y connotes new functionality/deprecation of existing functionality, and x connotes major new functionality/breaking changes; could this release be equivalently named 3.9.3?

Answer (score 0):

First off, we could not honestly say that CoreNLP has strictly used semantic versioning. Call what it uses "impressionistic versioning", if you will.

That said, we definitely decided to move to v4 to reflect the fact that the upgrade will break downstream code for most users.

However, things are subtle with NLP software. There are no big changes in the APIs, and while there are some changes in Properties, such as for the tokenizer, most properties have not changed either, and all the ones you have above look fine. Indeed, if your pipeline downstream is details-agnostic, such as an all-ML pipeline, CoreNLP 4.0 probably won't break anything and you can just plug it in.

However, for most people, they will have made assumptions about details of the tokenization or the taxonomies of parts of speech, dependencies, etc., and then code changes will definitely be required.

E.g., if your existing code assumes details of English tokenization, such that parentheses will be rendered '-LRB-', '-RRB-' or that quotes will be turned into ASCII sequences like '``', then your code will need changes. If you assume that your Spanish tagger/parser will provide a "simplified AnCora" part-of-speech tag set rather than a UD tag set, then your code will need changes. If you assume that in dependency analyses that the dependency 'dobj' will mark direct objects (UDv1) then you will need to update some patterns or whatever to look for 'obj' instead (UDv2). Etc.

There is a more detailed set of release notes here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/releases/tag/v4.0.0 . But there isn't any precise record of all changes. Except the GitHub history....

Comment: Thanks for the response - useful insight. I've revved the version and gone through a few build/test cycles. If you stick to public interfaces the code compiles and builds successfully. The biggest breaking change for me is the move from UDv1 to UDv2, and yes, if you are looking for dobj (or iobj) it ain't there any more, so get your rewrite boots on.

Comment: btw - point taken on the github history, but there is a LOT of code reformatting noise in those commits. You don't make it easy for casual/external observers to understand functional changes from the diffs.

Comment: Yup, fair enough, but we don't have anything detailed....